# Not able to get decimal value in nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, mysql-workbench

While executing the stored procedure in MySQL workbench it return which I have mentioned below

| supplierName | price | updatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Trading Pte Ltd | 40.0000 | 2021-04-05 |

But in API I am not able to get the that price decimal value. which has beeb mentioned below

```
[
    [
        {
             "supplierName":"Trading Pte Ltd",
             "price":40,
             "updatedDate":"2021-04-04T18:30:00.000Z"
        }
    ], {

          "fieldCount":0,
          "affectedRows":0,
          "insertId":0,
          "serverStatus":34,
          "warningCount":0,
          "message":"",
          "protocol41":true,
          "changedRows":0
       }
]
```

My nodejs code

```
router.get('/getItemPrice/:p_id',(req, res)=>{
    mysqlConnection.query("CALL getItemPrice(?)", 
    [req.params.p_id],(error, results, fields)=>{
        if(!error){
            res.status(200).json(results)
            console.log(results)
            }else{
            res.status(400).json("Failed To Get An Data:" + error);

        }
    })

})
```

Comment: Where's the code that is trying to access the `price` field?

Comment: There is no difference between "40" and "40.000".  The only difference is in how you print it.

Comment: And maybe even the stored proc comes in to play.

Comment: I am using the data need to be print in input box of angular. The expected output to show the 40.0000 not 40 because, some data are like this 4.2221. So all the data(price) is need to look like same.